# List of different types

Tags: c#

I have list of feed item objects and each feed item object has an Attributes property which in turn is also a list. However, this list needs to vary and I need to be able to later infer from the attributes what type of feed item I'm looking at.

I've tried several things so far, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around them as I do not entirely understand the more specific OOP concepts like generics. Here's what I have arrived at so far:

```
public class FeedItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<object> Attributes { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the list:

```
var feedData = new List<FeedItem>();
feedData.Add(new FeedItem
        {
            Date = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3),
            Type = "library",
            Id = 1,
            Attributes = new List<Paper>() { 
             ... add papers here ... 
            }
        });
```

The problem I run into is that it's trying to convert Paper in object. The idea is to keep the Attributes property open to having a list of varied objects, as I do want to insert Papers, Authors, Publications, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you initialize `Attributes` as `new List<Paper>()` instead of `new List<object>()`?

Comment: Create a base class for `Papers`, `Authors`, `Publications` and use that instead of `List<object>`, *Although not really sure how `Author` and `Paper` could be related in a class model*

Comment: Maybe create an `IAttribute` interface that `Paper`, `Author`, and `Publication` all implement and use a `List<IAttribute>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need `FeedItem` to be generic:

```
public class FeedItem<T>
{
    public List<T> Attributes { get; set; }
}

var feedData = new List<FeedItem<Paper>>();
feedData.Add(new FeedItem<Paper>
    {
        Attributes = new List<Paper>() {

        }
    });
```

If you need multiple types of attributes in one list (but given that in your example you explicitly create a `List<Paper>`, I don't think you do), then have `Paper`, `Author`, etc. implement a common interface and type the `List` to that. They must all offer some common functionality - a list of a bunch of completely different things is useless, right?

Comment: This is almost what I need. Like you mentioned in your answer though, the list needs to contain feed items of different types. So instantiating a List<FeedItem<Paper>> would limit me to just a list of those. I need a list of feed items of different types. The real world scenario is that I may have added authors to my interests, or added papers to my library, or modified my profile page. All those actions would be different types of FeedItems and they would all be in the list (that gets turned into JSON and spat out to the client).

Comment: @Ainxty In that case I would make `FeedItem` non-generic and make `Attributes` a list of `IAttribute` which exposes the relevant properties. If they have no common properties then it's not clear what use the list is going to be and you should probably define a common structure that you can map to.

Answer (score 1):

A `List<Paper>` is *not* a `List<object>` - because it can only hold `Paper`s.  You can either declare it as a `List<object>` (or some other common base type to all of the types you want to support) and fill it with `Papers`:

```
feedData.Add(new FeedItem
        {
            Date = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3),
            Type = "library",
            Id = 1,
            Attributes = new List<object>() { 
             ... add papers here ... 
            }
        });
```

or make `FeedItem` generic - the drawback here is you must predefine what type of attributes the `FeedItem` can have:

```
public class FeedItem<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<T> Attributes { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

var feedData = new List<FeedItem<Paper>>();
feedData.Add(new FeedItem<Paper>
        {
            Date = new DateTime(2015, 3, 3),
            Type = "library",
            Id = 1,
            Attributes = new List<Paper>() { 
             ... add papers here ... 
            }
        });
```

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers. This helped me as well. :) Thanks!